# inet_netof() function returns strange value

Tags: c, sockets, networking

```
        addr4 = &((struct sockaddr_in *)ifa->ifa_netmask)->sin_addr;
        internal_addr = inet_netof(*addr4);
        printf("IPv4 MASK %08x \n",internal_addr);
```

I have the above code. It is printing the IPv4 MASK as

```
IPv4 MASK 00ffffff
```

I am assuming this represents `255.255.255.0`. Is that correct assumption? 
I want to convert that to `24` (an integer in CIDR notation)

Comment: yes, but to print it correctly, use `printf("IPv4 MASK %08x\n", ntohl(internal_addr));`  as everything here is in network byte order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IPv4 MASK 00ffffff
```

> I am assuming this represents 255.255.255.0. Is that correct assumption?

That's correct.
`00ffffff` in network byte order becomes `0xff 0xff 0xff 0x00`, which in turns, becomes `255.255.255.0` in `dot notation`

Answer (score 2):

Per your desire to convert it to the number of mask bits (CIDR notation), just count the number of one bits in the mask.

Just loop through the 32-bit, unsigned integer (`0x00ffffff`), checking if it is greater than 0, if it is greater than 0 add 1 to your answer, then divide the unsigned integer by 2 (or shift it right 1 bit).